# Why does my HTML signature appear correctly in Thunderbird, but incorrectly in Outlook?

Tags: html, outlook, thunderbird

I've written some small HTML code to use as a signature in Thunderbird. The display is perfect and works without error for emails received by Thunderbird. However when an email from me is received in Outlook, color information is missing.

Here is my HTML code (with names and identifying information replaced)

```
<html>
  <div class="Section1">
    <p><b><span style="font-size: 10pt;
          font-family:Arial,sans-serif; color: rgb(35, 53,
          64);padding-left: 10px;">
          <!--  NAME  -->
          First </span>
          <span style="font-size: 10pt;
          font-family:Arial,sans-serif; color: rgb(223, 93,
          39);"> Last <br>
        </span></b> 
        <span style="font-size: 9pt; font-family:
        Arial,sans-serif; color: rgb(35, 53, 64);padding-left:
        10px;">
        <!--    Job Title   -->
        Mobile App Developer
        &nbsp;<br>
      </span>
      <!--COMPANY NAME--> <b><span style="font-size: 11pt;
          font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color: rgb(223, 93,
          39);padding-left: 10px;">Company</span></b><b><span
          style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
          color: rgb(35, 53, 64);">Name &reg;</span></b></p>
    <p>
      </span> <span style="font-size: 9pt; font-family:
        Arial,sans-serif; color: rgb(35, 53, 64);padding-left:
        10px;"><a class="moz-txt-link-abbreviated"
          href="mailto:email@email.com" style="color: rgb(35,
          53, 64);text-decoration:none;">
          <!--EMAIL ADDRESS--> email@email.com</a></span> | <span
        style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; color:
        rgb(223, 93, 39);">My.Name &nbsp;Skype</span><br>
      <b><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family:
          Arial,sans-serif; color: rgb(35, 53, 64);padding-left:
          10px;"><a class="moz-txt-link-abbreviated"
            href="http://www.google.com" style="color: rgb(35, 53,
            64); text-decoration:none;">
            <!--WEBSITE URL--> www.google.com</a></span></b></p>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Outlook:

[image: Outlook]

Thunderbird:

[image: Thunderbird]

I'm not sure what the issue is as I have very little experience with HTML. I took most of this code from someone else's signature block.

Comment: May we see a screenshot of the email in each email client?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment to take some screenshots.

Comment: Screenshots have been added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the hexadecimal code instead of `rgb(r, g, b)`.
For example, replace `rgb(35, 53, 64)` occurences with `#233540`.

You can use http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm to figure out the hex code.